# IME in landscape view is not working - Next button does not respond

Tags: android-layout, keyboard, navigation

I have an app, one activity is a form with multiple fields. In landscape mode when clicking into the first field the fullscreen IME kicks in, with a "Next" button.

The "Next" button, however, does not respond at all.  No errors are thrown, nothing logged related to this - it just doesn't move to the next (of about 12) text fields.

Same (lack of) behavior when other fields are selected on the form and text entered/not entered in landscape view - non-responsive next button.

The final EditText field correctly shows a "Done" button...which is also unresponsive.

I've had no luck searching forums and Googling this, and nothing I've been able to find related to the IME has helped to this point.

One option, of course, is to force portrait mode (which works fine), but I would rather avoid that klunky workaround.

Any suggestions, references to code/examples related to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved using android:imeOptions="actionDone" in the EditText layout if the next element is not an EditText view, or if at the end of the form.  All other EditText layouts added android:imeOptions="actionNext".

This allows a full-screen IME in landscape view to navigate from one EditText to the next, form an EditText out of the IME if the next field is a button or spinner (any non-EditText field), and exit the full-screen IME after the last form field.

Comment: For me it is not going to next editText also. I have read one more article which says i have to handle keyDown event and in that I have to request for focus to go to next editText.